# Deprecation of GCP legacy metadata endpoints - how to test if I'm not longer using them?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Thanks in advance for the help.

I received an email from Google Platform notifying me of the following

> Our records show that you own projects with App Engine applications or Cloud Functions that are still calling the pre-GA v0.1 and v1beta1 endpoints of the App Engine and Cloud Functions metadata server. After September 30, 2020, requests to the v0.1 and v1beta1 endpoints will no longer be supported, and may return HTTP 404 NOT FOUND responses. As a result, before September 30, 2020, you will need to update your requests to use the v1 endpoint, which was available starting in 2016.

After investigation, it turns out I'm using these endpoints indirectly as a result of "using an old Google client library which is making requests to the legacy endpoints".

I believe I've followed the instructions to upgrade all the old Google client libraries to address this problem, but I'm not positive. How can I confirm that my application is no longer using these legacy endpoints indirectly? I don't want my application to stop working on September 30th, but I have no way to know if I've successfully migrated.

Comment: This seems to be possible only for Google support, you may try to raise it on https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Comment: @vitooh I've already tried that route, but because I'm not on an enterprise plan, they won't let me contact their support team.